# send_keys is not working in phantomjs, but its working fine on firefox

Tags: phantomjs, watir-webdriver

I am unable to interact the text field `text_field(:css => '.search-query').send_keys(:enter)`
, its working fine on firefox and chrome , but not working in Phantomjs

```
<div class="search search-session">
  <form class="search-form search-form-session" action="#">
    <i class="icon-search"></i>
    <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query-session search-query" placeholder="Search">
  </form>
```

i think send_keys are not working in phatomjs ,can anyone help me with this

This is the error message

> :Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-

Comment: What is the error? Are you sure that the element is present in PhantomJS? PhantomJS has a small viewport size initially and the site may change the content based on user agent.

Comment: This is the error message :Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
the solution was to force a user Agent when initiating the web Driver (using DesiredCapabilities)
using something like that should do the trick :

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.phantomjs("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1468.0 Safari/537.36")
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs, :desired_capabilities => capabilities
browser = ::Watir::Browser.new driver
```

source : https://gist.github.com/tehprofessor/5497198

Comment: I tried this ,but no use , still getting error for send_keys in phantomjs with user agent of chrome / firefox

Comment: Please suggest me possible ways

Comment: try taking a screen shot to make sure that the field is editable, like described here : http://watirwebdriver.com/screenshots/